# form submission with multiple fields

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, meteor-blaze

I want if a user clicks on "Add More" button the **Ingredient Name** and **Amount** input fields  keeps adding on page.And when user submit the form after filling all other fields,all input values including **Ingredient Name** and **Amount** field get inserted in to Recipes collection. So later i can show complete recipe with its ingredients with amount on **show_recipe** page.I am not sure if i have to add **Ingredient Name** and **Amount** field values into some other collection to show them on show_recipe page.How ever i am not getting how to add all ingredients and their amount and then show them properly on show_recipe page .Can you please guide me how to do it.
complete source code is [here](https://github.com/soni1/foody)

**add_recipes.html**

```
 <template name="add_recipes">
        <form  class="add_recipe">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="name" >Recipe Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Please Enter the Recipe name">
            </div>
            <div class="form-inline mb">
                <div class="form-group">

                    <label for="ingredient">Ingredient Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="ingredient" id="ingredient" placeholder="Name">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="amount">Amount</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="amount" id="amount" placeholder="Amount ">
                </div>
                <button  class="btn btn-default addMore">Add More</button>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="des" >How to prepare</label>

                <textarea class="form-control" type="text" name="description" rows="3" id="des">
                </textarea>

            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="time" >Time to prepare</label>

                <input class="form-control" type="number" name="time"  id="time" placeholder="Time required to make the recipe. (In Minutes)">

            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="prodImg">Please Select the Image of your Recipe</label>
                <input type="file" id="recipeImage" name="recipeImage">
            </div>

            <div>
                <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success "> Add Recipe</button>
                <a href="/" class="btn btn-default">Close</a>
            </div>
        </form>
    </template>
```

**add_recipes.js**

```
Template.add_recipes.events({
    'submit .add_recipe':function(event){
        var name = event.target.name.value ;
        var ingredient = event.target.ingredient.value ;
        var amount = event.target.amount.value ;
        var description = event.target.description.value ;
        var time= event.target.time.value ;
        var file = $('#recipeImage').get(0).files[0];
        if(file){
            fsFile = new FS.File(file);
            RecipesImages.insert(fsFile,function(err,result){
                if(!err){
                    var recipeImage = '/cfs/files/RecipesImages/'+ result._id;
                    Recipes.insert({
                        name:name,
                        description:description,
                        image:recipeImage,
                        time:time,
                        createdAt: new Date()
                    })
                }
            });

        } else{

            var recipieImage = '/img/noimage.png';

            Recipes.insert({
                name:name,
                description:description,
                image:recipesImages,
                time:time,
                createdAt: new Date()
            })
        }
        // Clear the form
        event.target.name.value  = "";
        event.target.ingredient.value = "";
        event.target.amount.value = "";

        event.target.description.value = "";
        event.target.time.value= "";
        FlashMessages.sendSuccess('Recipe Added',{ autoHide: true, hideDelay: 3000 });
        Router.go('/');
        event.preventDefault();
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I would Suggest you use Simple Schema and Autoform to Achieve This

Create A simple Schema

```
    ReceipeSchema = new SimpleSchema({
      // All the Other Properties as per your Requirement for "Add More" Feature use the below 
      ingredients: {
        type: [Object],
        minCount: 1
      },
,
    "ingredients.$.Name": {
        type: String
    },
    "ingredients.$.amount": {
        type: String
    }
    });
```

Attach the SimpleSchema to a Collection like this

`Receipe.attachSchema(ReceipeSchema );`

Then inside your Html add

```
<template name="insertReceipeForm">
  {{> quickForm collection="Receipe" id="insertReceipeForm" type="insert"}}
</template>
```

Viola !! you will be automatically able to see a plus Button to include as many ingredients as you want and it will be stored as an array.

For More information on 
SimpleSchema https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema

Collection2  https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-collection2

Autoform  https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform

Happy Coding !!